# Questions about Spring Security

Tags: java, android, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am actually beginner in Spring framework. For today i've faced with problems and i want ask you a couple questions to figure it out.

I want to make simple user login/authorisation app with Android client.

First of all I want to post my code:

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {
    public User() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "userName", nullable = false)
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "userPassword", nullable = false)
    private String userPassword;

    @Transient
    private String confirmPassword;


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public void setPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }
}
```

Services:

User details:

```
@Service("userDetailsServiceImpl")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUserName(userName);

        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

Impl of `UserSerice` interface:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    public void save(User user) {
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public User findByUserName(String userName) {
        return userRepository.findByUserName(userName);
    }
}
```

User validator:

```
@Component
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class aClass) {
        return User.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        User user = (User) o;

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "username", "Required");

        if (user.getUsername().length() < 8 || user.getUsername().length() > 32) {
            errors.rejectValue("username", "Size.userForm.username");
        }

        if (userService.findByUserName(user.getUsername()) != null) {
            errors.rejectValue("username", "Duplicate.userForm.username");
        }

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "Required");
        if (user.getPassword().length() < 8 || user.getPassword().length() > 32) {
            errors.rejectValue("password", "Size.userForm.password");
        }

        if (!user.getConfirmPassword().equals(user.getPassword())) {
            errors.rejectValue("confirmPassword", "Different.userForm.password");
        }
    }
}
```

Impl of `SecurityService`

```
@Service
public class SecurityServiceImpl implements SecurityService {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public String findLoggedInUsername() {
        Object userDetails = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
        if (userDetails instanceof UserDetails) {
            return ((UserDetails) userDetails).getUsername();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void autoLogin(String username, String password) {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());

        authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);

        if (authenticationToken.isAuthenticated()) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);

        }
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan("com.webserverconfig.user")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

And the lsat one -> Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Autowired
    private UserValidator userValidator;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public User registration(@RequestBody User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        userValidator.validate(user, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            //What should i return here to my Android client ?
        }

        userService.save(user);

        securityService.autoLogin(user.getUsername(), user.getConfirmPassword());

        return user;

    }

}
```

I am missing some classes here for saving space.

I am asking you for help me with my questions, please:

1) When i am trying to send JSON using Postman:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "userName": "Andrew",
  "userPassword": "apoyark123",
  "confirmPassword": "apoyark123"
}
```

I am getting next erorr:

```
DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unrecognized field "userName" (class com.webserverconfig.user.entity.User), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "id", "name", "password", "confirmPassword"])
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@ddd416; line: 3, column: 16] (through reference chain: com.webserverconfig.user.entity.User["userName"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "userName" (class com.webserverconfig.user.entity.User), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "id", "name", "password", "confirmPassword"])
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@ddd416; line: 3, column: 16] (through reference chain: com.webserverconfig.user.entity.User["userName"])
```

Am i missing some annotation ?

**This issue resolved by Mehdi in the first comment. !!!**

**Please help me with second question.**

2) I am haven't tested security validation part yet, because this code doesn't working, but i have a question -> How my client will understand that login/authorisation have gone wrong/good ?

If we take a look on controller's method `registration(...)` -> what should i return to the client if first "if" false ?

What if validation is not correct ? What should i return to the client and how ?

Comment: in your user model you declare the setter as setName where it should be setUsername same for password

Comment: Thank you, now it works fine.

Comment: About second question: you can throw another status (instead of HttpStatus.CREATED) and on the client side just handle it.